# Flipping a child sprite's xscale in Spritekit using Swift

Tags: swift

Alright I'm offically stumped. I've been able to figure out my problems myself in the past but I'm lost on this one.

I'm trying to flip a child sprite's xscale. I want the flip to occur when the child's x position is negative. With the code below, the sprite does flip, every time the sprite reaches negative position, it loops back and forth flipping until reaching positive again.

I've tried numerous variations, but this is the code in it's simplest form. Any help or alternatives would be appreciative.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */


        let pin = childNodeWithName(Pin1) as SKSpriteNode!

        let guyPoint = guy.convertPoint(guy.position, fromNode: pin)

        if guyPoint.x <= 0 {
            guy.xScale = -1
        }
            else {
                 guy.xScale = 1
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

So if it is constantly flipping it's probably an issue of coordinate space. So check to make sure your convertPoint method is accurately returning the point you want. I would use println() to see what's going on there.

Probably what's happening is you want to flip the xScale when the child node is negative in the scene space or something (i.e. when the child is off the screen) but instead guyPoint might be the position of the child in its parent's coordinate space (so relative to the parent).

Also try with and without the else{} part to see if that changes anything.